# How to get input numbers from the user and sort it before printing it in python

Tags: python, string, function

I want to get input numbers from the user and sort it then print it. But it gives attribute error:

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'sort'

-- with the code--

```
lucky_numbers = input("Write your favourite numbers: ")
ans = (lucky_numbers)
ans.sort()
print(ans)
```

Comment: If you enter a string of numbers (for example, separated by spaces), you need to store the numbers in `list` and  then sort it.

Comment: Hey @wink - understand, what you have done, before posting the problem, its the basic that, the inputted characters will be string in python and needs `typecasting` before it can be `sorted`

Answer (score 0):

Using `split()`:

```
lucky_numbers = input("Write your favourite numbers with a space: ")
numberList = lucky_numbers.split()
numberList.sort()
print(numberList)
```

OUTPUT:

```
Write your favourite numbers with a space: 50  40 -10                                                                                                                        
['-10', '40', '50']
```

EDIT:

If you want to have the values in `int`:

```
numberList = [int(x) for x in numberList]
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be possible answer. You also need to convert str values to int

```
lucky_numbers = input("Write your favourite numbers: ")
ans = lucky_numbers.split()
ans_int = [int(i) for i in ans] 
ans_int.sort()
print(ans_int)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't sort it because the input function returns the string that has been typed by the user so it will be a string not a list and you can't sort it. Your approach must change and you must store user input and numbers in a list.
Something like this may work:

```
lucky_numbers = []

while True:
    user_input = input('enter your favourite number or to exit enter Q:')
    if user_input == 'Q':
        break
    else:
        lucky_numbers.append(int(user_input))

lucky_numbers.sort()
print(lucky_numbers)
```

This only works for integers and there is more stuff you can do for type checking and making sure that user input is a number or no or the list is empty or not. It was just a simple example to show the overall process.